# edittext, custom keyboard et textWatcher

Tags: android

I work on an application that contains 9 edittext and a custom keyboard all works perfectly but when I add a textWatcher to my editext the number will be reversed for example if I insert the value 14 in edittext1 it will be 41 I also want if I have a value in edittext among the 9 I can not insert in the other editext remaining the code if it works of 0 .... 9 if for example I insert the value 1 in edittext1 and I want to insert the value 14 in edittext2 I can not because 1 repeats .help me if you please I am debitant in the development android and here is the code that I use

```
   public void editTextWatcher(final EditText edt) {
    edt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            edt.removeTextChangedListener(this);
            edt.setText("");
            edt.addTextChangedListener(this);

            ArrayList<String> texts = new ArrayList<String>();
            texts.add(et1.getText().toString());
            texts.add(et2.getText().toString());
            texts.add(et3.getText().toString());
            texts.add(et4.getText().toString());
            texts.add(et5.getText().toString());
            texts.add(et6.getText().toString());
            texts.add(et7.getText().toString());
            texts.add(et8.getText().toString());
            texts.add(et9.getText().toString());

            for (String text : texts) {
                if (s.toString().equals(text)) {
                    if (s.toString().equals("")) {
                        return;
                    }

                    AlphaAnimation animation1 = new AlphaAnimation(0.2f, 1.0f);
                    animation1.setDuration(70);
                    animation1.setStartOffset(500);
                    animation1.setFillAfter(true);
                    edt.startAnimation(animation1);
                    edt.removeTextChangedListener(this);
                    edt.addTextChangedListener(this);
                    afficheerr1();

                    return;

                } else {

                }
            }

            edt.removeTextChangedListener(this);
            edt.setText(s.toString());
            edt.addTextChangedListener(this);

        }
    });
}
```

et le code dans onCreate

```
  editTextWatcher(et1);
    editTextWatcher(et2);
    editTextWatcher(et3);
    editTextWatcher(et4);
    editTextWatcher(et5);
    editTextWatcher(et6);
    editTextWatcher(et7);
    editTextWatcher(et8);
    editTextWatcher(et9);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can remove these lines:

```
edt.removeTextChangedListener(this);
edt.setText("");
edt.addTextChangedListener(this);
```

The issue here is you're removing the text and cursor jumps to the beginning of the string.

**OR**

The other option is to set cursor to end after you set text:

```
...

edt.removeTextChangedListener(this);
edt.setText(s.toString());
edt.setSelection(et.getText().length());    // move cursor to the end of string
edt.addTextChangedListener(this);

...
```

Btw, it's really unclear what this is supposed to do and what you're asking.

Comment: when I give a value to an edittext I can not give it to the other that is to say this number does not repeat in the eight edittext remaining the code that I use works with [0 .... 9] but the problem if I type for example 14 this number will be reversed it will be 41.